# Merge Array by value PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem, I would like to merge arrays by value. Below is a entry example, the entry array have a 100 records

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [code] => dfrr5tv5t5vt5
            [status] => online
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [code] => e32e3e2e2323e23e
            [status] => online
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [desc] => Some_description
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [desc] => Some_description_2
        )
    ....
)
```

I would like to get the following result through merge array by [id]

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [code] => dfrr5tv5t5vt5
            [status] => online
            [desc] => Some_description
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [code] => e32e3e2e2323e23e
            [status] => online
            [desc] => Some_description_2
        )

    ....
)
```

Comment: How are you obtaining these values? As I believe you might be able to do this before you have an array like this. As you could, for instance, set the key of the array to the ID, and this way add to that array easily as you get can add to that certain ID.

Comment: The PHP function [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) is the tool you need.

Comment: Not very likely because the data is downloaded in random order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use assocative arrays. Use `$row["id"]` as  associative index.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $row) {
    $result[$row["id"]] = isset($result[$row["id"]]) ? array_merge($result[$row["id"]], $row) : $row;
}
$result = array_values($result); // optional, this removes associative keys
```

Comment: How I can compare records by two key ?

Comment: @TyTus what do you mean?

Comment: In your solution, you are merge array by "id", but what if I want to merge array by two values "id" and "code". Of course, if the second array is the "code"